# max-width HTML property is not working in IE and Firefox, but it is in Chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have defined a table that uses the whole width of the page `width="100%"` and want to define images inside it that have as maximum the same width of the table `max-width="100%"`.
But it does not work for IE and Firefox!
I have read that if I donot define a width for the table these navigators are not considered the `max-width` attribute, but, what can I do to get what I need?

OK, I am editing my original question to be more specific:
HTML code (i.e. "paco.html"):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="myStyles.css"/>
</head>
<body>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td><img src="myImage.png"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the CSS code (myStyles.css):

```
table, td{
  width: 100%;
}
table td img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

...and this is all.

Comment: Please could you possibly include a code example or an image of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Here you are....                                     'contentDescription p img,
 .contentDescription table td img {
 max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
}'

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm going to have to ask you to be more specific, please could you edit your original question to include *all* problematic HTML and CSS code so we can get a better understanding of the issue?

Comment: Hello Sam, I've been more specific, as you asked for.

Comment: I see it is not a problem of being specific, Sam :-(

Answer (score 0):

The max-width attribute is CSS not HTML you have to either put it in your CSS or say:
`<img src="#" style="max-width: 666px;>`

For more information on Max-width check: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width)

Comment: OK, the max-width attibute is CSS and not HTML, but you have not answer my question. How do I do for obtaining got I need? Putting in a CSS sheet or in the own HTML donot change anything.

Comment: I tried it and i couldn't change the Image's size unless i put it into the `<img>`tag itself. `<img src="..." width="100%" />` but it also changed the height of it, so it keeps the same ratio in relation to the width. Is that what you wanted? Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/opferslayer/AYhf5/

Comment: Thanks for your help, but no. It is not what I need. I want my image not to grow more than the total width of the cell, but neither to grow more than its own width. If I use "width='100%'" then it doesn't grow more than the width of the cell, but it grows more than its own width.

Comment: So...nobody is able to help me??